# Accidentaly removed ubuntu from GRUB. How do I get it back?

Tags: grub2

I used grub-customizer to remove some old entries, but I made a mistake and now there's only Windows left in GRUB.

I tried booting into ubuntu through grub's command line but I don't know how to do anything there. Just booting once would be enough, or, if possible, fixing the listing right there in the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst the question is not identical, the answer is the same as [this AU Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13212/how-do-i-restore-grub-after-i-ran-a-fixmbr-command)

In summary - boot from a LiveCD and recreate your Grub as per both these linked answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your Grub is still there. You want to boot into Ubuntu and then run Grub Customizer and mark at least one kernel to appear in the Grub menu.

May I suggest that you do indeed run a live CD and browse the file system to boot/grub/grub.cfg? You do not need to edit this file. But find the part of the file that Grub uses to boot Ubuntu. Copy it down and use some of it as commands at the Grub command prompt to load into that kernel image. The key line would be the line that begins linux /boot/vmlinuz ... You may need to run each of the lines in that part of the menu entry one at a time in the order that they are listed.

Regards.