# Grub Stuck after install

Tags: grub2

I had Windows 7 running initially -- however, because a million people are complaining that the Alienware M17 from a few years back running Radeo HD3870 x2 are getting BSOD's left and right, I decided to drop it and tried to install 12.04 from USB.

I got through the entire installation OK,  but when it rebooted I got the grub command line because of an error.

I don't need Windows any more, I really just need to get Ubuntu installed so I can get back to D3. Lol. What do I do? I've tried rebooting from the USB but it does nothing, just kicks me back to grub command line.

Comment: it says error: no such device: 55594622-aabb-449a-96f1-9b23c069981f    grub rescue>

Comment: See these questions for instance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23418/what-do-i-select-for-grub-install-devices-after-an-update?rq=1  and http://askubuntu.com/questions/55120/accidentaly-removed-ubuntu-from-grub-how-do-i-get-it-back?rq=1

Comment: And another :  http://askubuntu.com/a/37983/8844