# Corrupted partition when it was updated to 11.04 including grub?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, filesystem, grub2, mbr

This problem seems centered around me, it has happened twice!

### Description of the Problem

My Linux partition (ext4) got corrupted. I believe a bad superblock ...

So when I boot my computer I get no grub just a flashing monitor.

I fixed it using Windows 7 DVD.

### Last Time this happened

I *accidentally* formatted my Ubuntu partition and so I reinstalled Ubuntu (10.04 32 - bit).

### When this problem pops out

When grub updates I believe .. because the last time I got this error was when I updated grub.

This time also I was updating Ubuntu from 10.04 to 11.04 and grub got updated and the partition got corrupted!

Any idea how to get my Ubuntu partition back and what is causing this problem?

Clarifications

My entire ubuntu partition is corrupted !!!

Comment: Can you try to make the question a bit clearer? I'm not exactly getting the point?

Comment: @Roland Any idea how to get my Ubuntu partition back ?

Comment: You said the problem was with grub booting the system, not loosing your Ubuntu partition.  Question is very unclear.

Comment: @psusi I edited it to make it more clear , I think that grub update corrupted my ubuntu partition !

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: @jrg It is abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really sure what you mean by a "corrupted" partition, but as it seems to me, you simply lost your bootloader (grub)

to get it reinstalled please follow the answer in this post:

[How do I restore grub after I ran a fixmbr command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13212/how-do-i-restore-grub-after-i-ran-a-fixmbr-command)

Comment: I do not know if that is the problem but I will try it out and post back !