# Windows 7 does not work after Linux installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

Yesterday I tried to install Ubuntu without Wubi, but it seems I got careless and didn't pay much attention to the partitioning details.

Now I'm able to use Ubuntu but I can't use Windows 7 anymore.

There is an option for loading Windows 7 in GRUB, but when I click that it simply redirects me to GRUB again and again until  I choose Ubuntu.

Then I tried Boot repair and BootSectorFix, but now it doesn't even redirects me anymore, it just shows a "_" at the top left part of a blank screen.

SO I followed [this advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135272/how-to-boot-into-windows-7-when-grub-is-installed-in-the-windows-partition)
and tried Boot Repair a second time. [Here is the pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13502172/)

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you login to Ubuntu now?

Comment: You installed grub to the PBR or partition boot sector of Windows boot. And that should not even be allowed. I think the bug was filed with 10.10 back then. But you can fix with testdisk if NTFS backup Boot Sector is valid. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix And with Windows fixboot often does not work as with grub in PBR, Windows will not recognize it as NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu and check if the Windows Partition is still there on your hard drive and that it can be viewed.
Use your Windows Disc to boot.
Select the "Repair this Computer" option.
Select the option to use command prompt.
Issue the following command:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

MAKE A BACKUP of your important files first.
you will then be able to boot into Windows only.
To restore GRUB follow the answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13212/how-do-i-restore-grub-after-i-ran-a-fixmbr-command) question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can log in to Ubuntu without any problem, then just run,

```
sudo os-prober && sudo update-grub
```

Restart and see if that fix it. If you can't login to Ubuntu either then let me know and I'd update the answer with specific instructions to repair your bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite surprising: After some Googling, I decided to check out the Notepad file (or whatever that is) for the GRUB editor. Turns out there was some error, and I edited some lines of it. Worked fine.